# Get the timestamp of the last and first day of a month in postgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am currently trying to figure out the equivalent functions in `PostgresSQL` for the below `MariaDB` functions:

```
SELECT
CONCAT(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY('2021-02-15 00:00:00'),INTERVAL 1 DAY),INTERVAL -1 MONTH), ' ', '00:00:00') AS first_day_of_the_month,
CONCAT(LAST_DAY('2021-02-15 23:59:59'), ' ' ,'23:59:59') AS last_day_of_the_month;
```

**Expected Result:**

```
first_day_of_the_month  |    last_day_of_the_month
------------------------|-------------------------------
2021-02-01 00:00:00     |    2021-02-28 23:59:59
```

---

I want to get the `last day` and the `first day` of the month of a certain date including the time `00:00:00` for the first day and `23:549:59` for the last day.

So far I am comming close to the expected result with these queries:

```
SELECT 

(date_trunc('MONTH', '2021-02-15 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::TIMESTAMP
+ '1 days'::INTERVAL - '1 months'::INTERVAL AS first_day_of_the_month,

(date_trunc('MONTH', '2021-02-15 23:59:59'::TIMESTAMP) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::TIMESTAMP AS last_day_of_the_month;
```

However, as you can see in the [DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2a5b6ee33de29b7aa01ae57e06b7d04a) for the `last_day_of_the_month` I am getting `00:00:00` instead of `23:59:59`.

How do I need to change the query to get the correct timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c3d54fe02bbbc4936288f678f9b2b07e)

```
/* Option 1: Certain Date */
SELECT
date_trunc('month', timestamp '2021-02-15 00:00:00') AS first_timestamp,
date_trunc('month', timestamp '2021-02-15 23:59:59') + interval '1 month - 1 second' AS last_timestamp;

/* Option 2: Current_date */
SELECT
date_trunc('month', current_date)::timestamp AS first_timestamp,
date_trunc('month', current_date)::timestamp + interval '1 month - 1 second' AS last_timestamp;
```

**First timestamp of month**

`date_trunc('month', ...)` normalizes the date to the first possible timestamp of the month. So it returns `00:00:00` of the first day of the month

**Last timestamp of month**

If you add a month to the previous result, you get the first day/timestamp (`00:00:00`) of the next month. If you subtract a day from this, you get the last day of the current month. Of course, you can subtract just a second to get `23:59:59` of the last day of the month as you expected.

Comment: I had to add ::Timestamp to your query to get the fully expected result. Is there are certain reason why you did not use ::Timestamp. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d44aeef326a8df1b85e621602e827855

Comment: When I use the date in my question instead of current_date I am getting error. What do I have to change to use a certain date: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a716260180eabd2567c48bbb5d1e04c6

Comment: @Michi: you are passing strings to the function, not `timestamp` [literals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT)

Comment: To the first question: date_trunc() returns a timestamp, so you don't need a cast: From the docu (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html): "date_trunc ( text, timestamp ) → timestamp". For the last date, which is an addition of date_trunc (timestamp) and interval, which also returns a timestamp. Docu: "timestamp + interval → timestamp"

Comment: Second question... oh @a_horse_with_no_name was faster. Simply writing `'2020-01-01 12:34:56'` creates no timestamp, it is a string. Of course, you need to cast it into type timestamp (or date, which works as well). But there is no need to cast a date column into timestamp when you want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

For the first day of the month:

```
date_trunc('month', the_date_column)
```

For the last day:

```
date_trunc('month', the_date_column) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day'
```

Or if you prefer:

```
date_trunc('month', date) + interval '1 month - 1 day'
```

If you really one one second from midnight on the last day, replace `day` with `second` in the logic.  I don't recommend that.  In fact, if you want to define a range of date, define an *open* range and just use the first day of the next month.  Then you can learn about [`tsrange`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) which builds this into the language.

Comment: I tried to apply your solution here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d96ef91ebb6b64c6ddf8fd59dd2bd649 but I am getting an error.

Comment: @Michi https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=815eff5238721782ebb06cbed660e91e